# Facebook Invalid keyhash error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

While Using Facebook sdk in my android application, I am facing a tricky problem.

I am using Motorola G, Genymotion and Samsung devices for testing purposes.

In both Genymotion and Samsung, I am able to login with facebook , but while Its come to the Motorola turn, I am facing **Invalid Keyhash Error.**

So, In which way should I proceed to tackle the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Key hash facebook android sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231225/invalid-key-hash-facebook-android-sdk)

Comment: Noup.I am facing this issue with only one device, not all..Thank you

Comment: Generate new keyhash with motorola device and add it to facebook project.

Comment: you authorization from web view or application fb?

Comment: @jaydroider
for every project on single machine, the hashkey should be same right.

Comment: @JayVyas Yes hashkey should be the same with single machine. But why i have suggested to generate new it's bcz you are facing issue only with motorola.

Comment: @JayVyas motorolla, samsung and genymotion login in all device in app fb?