# Cannot generate correct facebook key hash for release apk?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-facebook

Steps that I've tried, 
1) Generated the keyhash (although i got a warning/error as "keytool: command not found") from the official developer documentation.(`keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`)

[image]

2)Also tried the the keyhash shown in the error message while signing in.

Still, none of the above keyhashes worked, interesting i was successfully able to signin to facebook in my debug version.
Please Help

Comment: try to get keyhash via java function as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231225/invalid-key-hash-facebook-android-sdk/29092048#29092048

Comment: @AvinashRavilla According to the answer the correct keyhash is the one in my screenshot, but unfornately it is not workiing in my case

Comment: Whats the final command ? did you replace `YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS` and `YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH` ? also you can just manually type the keyhash shown in error in to the facebook console

Comment: YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS is the same I use while generating the signed apk, and key path is the path of the key_store.jks in keystore folder

Comment: @ManoharReddy I have also manually typed the keyhash with multiple verfication, but unfortunately Im still getting the same error

Comment: add when ever keyhash you are getting in facebook app , for example in above screen shot you are getting error for  `dQ...............4=`  add it in facebook console . also check for case sensitive and `zero`, `o`    mistakes

Comment: @ManoharReddy will this also work for the release apk

Comment: @ManoharReddy, and by Facebook console, you mean, developers.facebook.com->settings->basic, am i right? If yes the I have already verified the o O 0 errors, but still my issue remains

Comment: yes in basic->android ->keyhashes , add your keyhash

Comment: I've done exactly the same at the right time, but while signin in with the release version of the apk, Iam getting the same error, again and again.

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal did you obtain keyhash with java method ?